# JavaScript - Am I using await right?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asynchronous

In order to render my page properly by using jQuery `.load()` on multiple HTML templates in the right order for me to then fill in the blanks per page, I need to load the same template multiple times but have the internals configured individually.

Right now I'm just trying to return a resolved promise at the end of `htmlLoad` to make the `await` keywords in `loadPage` wait for each `htmlLoad` to finish so the next `htmlLoad` can execute.

As such, I did all this stuff:

```
async function loadPage(){

    await htmlLoad("pageTitle",function(){  htmlLoad_prep_pageTitle("About")  },"pageTitle_about"  )  ;

    await htmlLoad("aboutSnippet" );
    
    await htmlLoad("pageTitle", function(){  htmlLoad_prep_pageTitle("Skills")  },"pageTitle_skills"  );
    
    await htmlLoad("pageTitle", function(){  htmlLoad_prep_pageTitle("Credits")  },"pageTitle_credits"  );
}
```

and here is the `htmlLoad` function:

```
var currentDivName="";

function htmlLoad(htmlTemplateName,callbackFunc=null,htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId="") {


            htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId = toString_default(htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId,htmlTemplateName);

            currentDivName = '#htmlLoad_'+htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId;

            if(callbackFunc!=null){
             $(currentDivName ).load("jS/htmlLoad/html/"+htmlTemplateName+".html",function(){callbackFunc()});

            }else{
             $(currentDivName ).load("jS/htmlLoad/html/"+htmlTemplateName+".html");
            }
            
            return Promise.resolve();         
}
```

and here is the `pageTitle` callback function mentioned inside of `loadPage()`, it is in the same .jS file as `htmlLoad`:

```
function htmlLoad_prep_pageTitle(pgTitle){

    pgTitle = toString_default(pgTitle,"Unknown Title");

    $(currentDivName+' #pgTitle').html(pgTitle);

}
```

Is there a smarter way to do what I'm doing here?

**UPDATE:**
After some help in the comments, 2 of the functions have changed.

```
async function htmlLoad(htmlTemplateName,callbackFunc=null,htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId="") {



            htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId = toString_default(htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId,htmlTemplateName);

            currentDivName = '#htmlLoad_'+htmlTemplateName_nonUniformId;

            if(callbackFunc!=null){
             await $(currentDivName ).load("jS/htmlLoad/html/"+htmlTemplateName+".html",function(){callbackFunc()});

            }else{
             await $(currentDivName ).load("jS/htmlLoad/html/"+htmlTemplateName+".html");
            }



         
}
```

```
async function loadPage(){

    await htmlLoad("pageTitle",function(){  htmlLoad_prep_pageTitle("About")  },"pageTitle_about"  )  ;

    await htmlLoad("aboutSnippet" );
    
    await htmlLoad("pageTitle", function(){  htmlLoad_prep_pageTitle("Skills")  },"pageTitle_skills"  );
    
    await htmlLoad("pageTitle", function(){  htmlLoad_prep_pageTitle("Credits")  },"pageTitle_credits"  );
}
```

However, I'm still getting the exact same issue: Only one of the last of the HTML templates is being altered and it's random to which of the alterations it will obey. I'm losing it over here, what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Because you're not waiting for the Promise objects returned from `.load()` to resolve anyway, there's no point in most of your code. Just start the `.load()` calls and let them finish when they finish. Now, if you want to be able to detect *errors* etc, or have some control over the order in which the `.load()` calls are done, then `htmlLoad()` should be an `async` function and it should `await` the calls to `.load()`.

Comment: That's the trouble though, when I did all this without the async/await/promise business, the htmlLoad functions executed out of order. When I set the return in htmlLoad to be on a really short timeout function, this all executes perfectly.

Comment: They'll load out of order with your current code also, or at least they might, because each call to `.load()` *already* creates a Promise that will resolve when the HTTP request completes. You return `Promise.resolve()` so the `await` calls don't really do anything, and certainly don't depend on the actual HTTP requests in flight.

Comment: Indeed it does load out of order still, that's precisely the problem, I think I had it worded so in my original post but edits were made by someone trying to make my words more concise and it got a bit lost in translation. But if I don't need await or promise.resolve() or even an async function, how come the functions were not executing in the correct order? When I call htmlLoad outside of an async function, if I do it multiple times to the same template going to different <div> tags, then only the last HTML template actually alters and it's basically random in how it is altered.

Comment: You **do** need an `async/await` solution if you want to have control over the order; that was my point. If you make `htmlLoad()` also be an `async` function, and add `await` for the jQuery `.load()` calls, then that will be a big step forward.

Comment: Ah, now I see! Sorry, I misunderstood entirely, very new to JS and async programming in general. I'll give that a go now, thank you!